# breeze 1.4.8 & angular ajax adapter: how to customize ajax settings?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, breeze

My code:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("ajax", "angular", true);

...

var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');

ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        CompanyName: 'Hilo Hattie',
        ContactName: 'Donald',
        City: 'Duck',
        Country: 'USA',
        Phone: '808-234-5678'
    }
};
```

in line 14813 of breeze.debug.js:

```
ngConfig = core.extend(compositeConfig, ngConfig);
```

compositeConfig.method has a value of 'POST' until it is overwritten, because ngConfig.method has a value of 'GET'.

I imagine this question is relevant for any ajax setting, but of course I'm mainly struggling with how to post with the angular ajax adapter, so maybe there's an entirely better way to do that? this approach feels dirty anyway, but breeze.ajaxPost.js only works with the jQuery ajax adapter, right?

Comment: Agree that this is hacky. Looking into the matter. Stay tuned.

Comment: I just read the *breeze.ajaxpost.js* in GitHub and it looks like **it should work with the angular ajax adapter**. I confess I haven't tried it but my reading of the code suggests it should work fine. Did you try it? Do you have a test case showing that it doesn't work?

Comment: I did try it.  It didn't work, but it was trivial to get it working.  I'm not sure I know how to produce a proper test case, but I will try to figure it out.  Is the basic idea to start with the DocCode project, add angular.js and breeze.ajaxPost.js, and then create a new test modeled on the existing "Query using withParameters" test?

Comment: Can you identify what didn't work? and what you did to fix it? I don't mean the hack you wrote above; I mean your change to ajaxpost that did the trick. I really should demonstrate how to do a test with Angular. I've got it on my list. I have some [plunkers](http://plnkr.co/users/wardbell). The challenge, in this case, is to reveal the XHR request. Could do with angular-mocks ... if I took the time :(.

Comment: my changes to ajaxpost are also pretty hacky. for one, I don't know how to properly get ajaxpost to modify the angular ajax adapter rather than the jquery ajax adapter.  ajaxpost runs before I can initialize the angular adapter. (suggestions?) so, I just moved the functions in ajaxpost into the datacontext, where I then call divertAjaxImpl(ajaxAdapter) after initializing the angular adapter (super hacky).  I made two changes, commented with ***CHANGE***.  [before plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QrJ4fKXtr3aioLCHs4J9?p=info) / [after plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VtBI5MbVS51jMX9kGK93?p=info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 6 Oct 2014 update

We recently had reason to revisit *ajaxpost* and have updated both [the code](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.ajaxpost.js) and [the documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breezeajaxpostjs).

The original recommendation works. We're merely clarifying and updating the happy path.

A few points:

- The *ajaxpost* plug-in works for both jQuery and Angular ajax adapters.
- Those adapters long ago became aware of `adapter.defaultSettings.headers` and have blended them into your Breeze *ajaxpost* http calls (take heed, PW Kad).
- You must call `breeze.ajaxPost()` explicitly after replacing the default ajax adapter as you do when you use the 'breeze.angular' service.
- You can wrap a particular ajax adapter explicitly: `breeze.ajaxPost(myAjaxAdapter);` We just don't do that ourselves because, in our experience, it is sufficient to omit the params (`breeze.ajaxPost()`) and let the method find-and-wrap whatever is the active ajax adapter of the moment.

The documentation explains the Angular use case which I repeat here to spare you some time:

```
// app module definition
var app = angular.module('app', ['breeze.angular']);  // add other dependencies

// this data service abstraction definition function injects the 'breeze.angular' service
// which configures breeze for angular use including choosing $http as the ajax adapter
app.factory('datacontext', ['breeze', function (breeze) {    // probably inject other stuff too
    breeze.ajaxPost(); // wraps the now-current $http adapter
    //... your service logic
}]);
```

## Original reply

AHA!  Thanks for the plunker (and the clever use of the Todo-Angular sample's reset method!).

In brief, the actual problem is that *breeze.ajaxpost.js* extends the jQuery ajax adapter, not the angular ajax adapter. There is a timing problem.

The root cause is that you can't tell *breeze.ajaxpost.js* which adapter to wrap. It always wraps the default adapter at the time that it runs. As you've got your script loading now, the jQuery adapter is the current one when *breeze.ajaxpost.js* runs.

The workaround is to set the default adapter to the angular adapter before *breeze.ajaxpost.js* runs.

One way to do that is to load the scripts as follows ... adding an inline script to set the default ajax adapter to the "angular" version.

```
  <script src="breeze.debug.js"></script>
  <script>
        <!-- Establish that we will use the angular ajax adapter BEFORE breeze.ajaxpost.js wraps it! -->
        breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("ajax", "angular", true);
  </script>
  <script src="breeze.ajaxpost.js"></script>
```

Clearly this is a hack. We'll look into how we can change *breeze.ajaxpost.js* so you can wrap any ajax adapter at the time of your convenience.

Comment: Excellent.  Appreciate the extra time you took to explain the issue in depth.

Comment: BTW, I think that your plunker isn't quite producing the behavior I need (and mine wasn't either).  I'm pretty sure that ajaxpost needs to set the "data" property to JSON.stringify(postObj) rather than the "params" property.  I'm sure you'll get that all sorted out when you update ajaxpost to be a bit more angular friendly.

Comment: Yes, thanks for finding this bug in ajaxpost. I expect its author will repair that very soon. I updated the plunker to use whatever are the most current checked-in breeze libraries so that it will work properly when we commit the fix.

Comment: The [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CZmDV0QLPMNftKAHR4RQ) has been updated to show the proper configuration per Steve's repairs.

Comment: just top-class excellence and it's much appreciated.  thanks guys!

Comment: @Ward One note - `breeze.ajaxpost()` not `breeze.ajaxPost()` - came back for the upgrade notes and found the (Take Heed) to save me

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for finding this issue, and thanks Ward for bringing it to my attention.  I've updated the [breeze.ajaxpost.js](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/Labs/breeze.ajaxpost.js) code to use `.data` as you described, and added a function you can call after adapter initialization.  So now you can do:

```
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("ajax", "angular");
ajaxAdapter.setHttp($http);
breeze.ajaxpost.configAjaxAdapter(ajaxAdapter);  // now we can use POST
```

So, it's slightly less hacky.

Comment: Another note is that by using AjaxPost you lose the ability to include custom headers.  Breeze writes the custom headers but AjaxPost doesn't incorporate this.  I am working on a pull request to use this - is the source on GitHub to be able to use?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is applicable to the following plugins and version: 
Breeze.Angular v.0.8.7 
Breeze.AjaxPost v.1.0.6

I just saw a new plugin called Breeze.Angular.js that can work in conjunction with Breeze.AjaxPost.js

You have to modify the Breeze.AjaxPost.js in order for it to work. Breeze.Angular.js initializes your adapter when your page loads, and Breeze.AjaxPost.js will take in the adapter initialized from Breeze.Angular.js

You can learn more about the Breeze.Angular server here: [breeze-angular-service](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-angular-service) 
You can learn more about Breeze.Ajaxpost here: [breeze-ajaxpost](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breezeajaxpostjs)

Now to set this up wasn't exactly apparent, because I took both files exactly as they were in git.

1.) Reference the files in this order:

> ```
> <script src="Scripts/q.min.js"></script>
> <script src="Scripts/breeze.angular.js"></script>
> <script src="Scripts/breeze.ajaxpost.js"></script>
> ```

2.) Go into your breeze.ajaxpost.js

Remove this line (or comment this line):

```
breeze.ajaxpost(); // run it immediately on whatever is the current ajax adapter
```

The reason why is because, this will cause your ajaxpost method to run before your breeze.angular service. When you go into the ajaxpost method, the ajaxAdapter parameter that is supposed to be passed in will be null. Removing this line appends the functionality for later in your code, so you can call it from the breeze.angular service.

3.) In breeze.angular.js go to your useNgHttp method. It should look like this:

```
// configure breeze to use Angular's $http ajax adapter
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("ajax", "angular");
ajaxAdapter.setHttp($http);
breeze.ajaxpost(ajaxAdapter);  // now we can use POST
```

When you run your program, both plugins should be able to set up the environment for you without having to include it in every javascript that makes your calls to the webapi.

Thanks guys for the plugins.