# Authorization when using plupload to upload images with Breeze

Tags: breeze, plupload

I'm using plupload in my Breeze/Durandal application to upload photos.

As part of configuring plupload in a given viewmodel, I set its `url` configuration property to point to an action on a Web API controller that is decorated with `BreezeController` and `Authorize`.

Examining the network trace in the browser developer tools, I see that the user's authorization info doesn't make it into the request. This actually makes sense, because the ajax isn't happening within breeze.

Any thoughts on how to properly secure this call to upload the image? I'd like access to the authenticated user id, otherwise I would have just let it be anonymous.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:** There's a headers option which allows you to set the request headers. Missed this when I was going through the documentation initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a headers option which allows you to set the request headers. Missed this when I was going through the documentation initially.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to tunnel an AJAX request through Breeze?  This can be done using the Breeze.AjaxPost.js adapter.

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breezeajaxpostjs

This would be used similar to a query except that you would attach a payload somehow -

```
var payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

// Query to post your payload
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from('api/postsomething')
        .withParameters({
            $method: 'POST',
            $encoding: 'JSON',
            $data: payload
        });

    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(saveSucceeded).fail(saveFailed);
}
```

Now, this example is stringifying some JSON to post to the server, how you would do this with an image is beyond me but this should hopefully get you started.

In fact, I forgot about this answer which should provide some extra resources if you need them - [breeze 1.4.8 & angular ajax adapter: how to customize ajax settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268636/breeze-1-4-8-angular-ajax-adapter-how-to-customize-ajax-settings)